# error: asm/uaccess.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, struct

I'm running linux kernel no. 2.6.15.51 on a ubuntu system.

I created a custom system call and added it to the kernel (containing a struct), compiled, and  booted into the new kernel. Now I'm trying to create a c file that calls that system call (for testing purposes). Because I have a struct declared in my system call file, I am including the header in my test file so I can use that same struct. However, when I try including my system call file (which makes a call to access_ok() method), I get an error saying asm/uaccess.h (the file where access_ok() is declared) does not exist. Any ideas why I could be having this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Does that file exist on your machine?  If it does, is it in a place your compiler can find it?